# Regex for a certain statement

Tags: regex

I am not really sharp on my regex knowledge and I would like some help.

My regex needs to find patterns of this such forms:

```
ban_454353453fnffgfhffzy1u9tpkmfetq3kia4jo1m1xr1jygbtr9s1xists34
ban_3zh89bxxzsf8fjxrptzy1u9tpkmfetq3kia4jygbtr9s1xists34jo1m1xr1
```

and so on.

So what do we have here?

1. Always starts with `ban_` - that's 4 characters.
2. 60 characters of random number of the forms [0-9] or [a-z], none of it is a capital letter.

Overall it's 64 characters.

I know it should start  with `$ban_` and continue with `[0-9]|[a-z]+` but I am not sure about the correct pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At their simplest, regexes are just a list of specifiers of *what* to match and *how many* should be there. You don't need to know the overall length of the string, or the length of things that are to be matched exactly.

So, taking your definition:

1. Always starts with "ban_". The *what* is the exact characters `ban_`. The *how many* is exactly one of each, so we don't need anything more than that.
2. 60 characters of random number of the forms [0-9] or [a-z]. The *what* here is the "character class" `[0-9a-z]` - note that we can combine the two ranges into one definition. The *how many* is exactly 60, which is written `{60}` so we write `[0-9a-z]{60}`

That gives us, quite simply `ban_[0-9a-z]{60}`

We may then want to add two things:

- `^` at the start of the regex means "this pattern must occur at the very beginning of the input" (e.g. `^ban_[0-9a-z]{60}`)
- `$` at the end of the regex means "this pattern must occur at the very end of the input" (e.g. `ban_[0-9a-z]{60}$`)
- combining the two means "the entire input must match this pattern, not just contain it somewhere" (e.g. `^ban_[0-9a-z]{60}$`)

Note that the definition of "input" depends how you're using the regex - it might be a whole file, one line of it, or a variable input in a form.